# how to insert name value if id in array of objects matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to insert name value if id in array of objects matches

```
var array = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "rohan1",
  "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "rohan2",
    "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
},
{
   "id":2,
   "name": "rohan3",
   "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
},
{
   "id":3,
   "name": "rohan3",
   "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
}]
```

this is an array of object.

I need below output:

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "name": "rohan1,rohan2",
   "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
},{
   "id":2,
   "name": "rohan3",
   "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
},
{
   "id":3,
   "name": "rohan3",
   "managerName": 'Charlic Martin'
}]
```

Comment: Can someone have same id and different names ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id from each object to create a map. If object having same id is found again, it will just concat names of the two objects

```
function groupObjects(arr) {
    const unique = {};
    arr.forEach(item => {
        const {id, name} = item;
        unique[id] ? unique[id]['name'] += `,${name}` : unique[id] = item;
    });
    return Object.values(unique);
}
```